# Is there a way to remove padding of image button in bootstrap 5?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I have one button with image inside of it and I want to remove padding, but it seems that it didn't work. I already tried to remove it with `style="padding:0px !important"` or use `p-0` class. Also, I changed the `<button>` with `<a>` and it works, but I lost those clicky effect.

Any solution please?

[image: this image button]

[image: inspect elemen]

My HTML Navbar:

```
<nav class="d-flex icon_ah navbar sticky-top navbar-dark bg-dark navbar-expand-lg p-0">
    <div>
        <form action="#">
            <button type="submit" class="navbar-toggler p-0 m-2 border-0">
                <span class="bi bi-house-fill"></span>
            </button>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div>
        <form class="btn-group">
            <button class="navbar-toggler p-0 m-2 border-0" id="dropdownMenuButton1" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false" data-bs-display="static">
                <span class="bi bi-plus-circle"></span>
            </button>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu bg-dark d-lg-none" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton1">
                <?php for ($i = 0; $i < count($item_ah); $i++) { ?>
                    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="<?= $item_ah[$i][1]; ?>"><?= $item_ah[$i][0]; ?></a></li>
                <?php } ?>
            </ul>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="ms-auto">
        <form class="btn-group">
            <button class="navbar-toggler p-0 m-2 border-0" id="dropdownMenuButton2" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false" data-bs-display="static">
                <img class="rounded" style="height:29.33px;" src="\img\system\user.png" alt="user-glories">
            </button>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item icon_ahm">
                <a class="nav-link" href="<?= base_url('#'); ?>">
                    <b class="bi bi-house-fill"></b> Dashboard</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item dropdown icon_ahm">
                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                    <b class="bi bi-plus-circle-fill"></b> New
                </a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu bg-dark" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                    <?php for ($i = 0; $i < count($item_ah); $i++) { ?>
                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="<?= $item_ah[$i][1]; ?>"><?= $item_ah[$i][0]; ?></a></li>
                    <?php } ?>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

My CSS:

```
.sampul {
  width: 70px;
}

.table > tbody > tr > * {
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.icon_ah > div > button,
.icon_ah > div > form > button {
  font-size: 29.33px;
}

.icon_ahm > ul > li > a,
.icon_ahm {
  font-size: 13px;
}

.dropdown-item {
  color: #b4b9be;
}

.dropdown-item:hover {
  color: rgb(85, 85, 85);
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.856);
}

.dropdown-item:active {
  color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.363);
}
```

Comment: Have you tried setting something like `padding: 0 !important;` on .btn or button in your stylesheet?

Comment: can you do inspect element and share that screenshot so have a complete knowledge what is actually a problem

Comment: Replicate the issue without the php code - I cannot JSFiddle your given code.

Comment: @Loupeznik Yeah i did, and it still not working... I wonder why.

Comment: @JyotiAhluwalia Hmm, ok i'll try...

Comment: Can you create a code snippet, so we can see it live?

Comment: @Vino thanks for your response, tbh i'm still newbie, i don't even know how to use JSFiddle yet. So i will learn it later.

Comment: @AndrewSavetchuk I do want to do that too... But unfortunately, i still need to learn how to do it first, i'm sorry.

Comment: I saw the screenshot, the image is having a height and would be helpful if the parent div of the image portion is shown or else what you can do is if its live somewhere send the link because its too hard to figure out by seeing only pictures

Comment: @Gunping you can create a snippet on CodePen, take a look at codepen.io

Comment: @JyotiAhluwalia Ahh thanks again for your response, i already put my css to this post, when i check it again, i just figure it out, this problem caused by my css, i don't really know why `font-size` also effecting the image inside the button. I think i need to evaluate my code again, and find another way to separate font and image size.

Comment: yes it does see if you have included reset css may be this will solve your problem or else put font size or that one button with the image inside

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to change box-sizing to content-box?